# Trig proving the identity

Tags: trigonometry

The question is : $\sin^2 \theta \sec^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta -1$

I have tried many different methods but I cannot seem to figure out how to approach this so the both sides are equal.

Comment: "&" implies what here?

Comment: I'd safely assume it's an angle. I edited it so it is clearer, awaiting approval.

Comment: Yes it is an angle, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, If "&" symbol indicates the angle.. then if I write angle as $\theta$, then the matter to prove is : $\sin^2 \theta \sec^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta - 1$..
 and i infer here to editor... it can't be $\sec 2\theta$ it must be $\sec^2 \theta $.. 
Now, $\sin^2 \theta \sec^2 \theta = \tan^2 \theta = sec^2 \theta-1$, as the pythagorean identity $\tan^2 \theta + 1=\sec^2 \theta$

Answer (score 0):

$$sin^2\theta*sec^2\theta=\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta}=tan^2\theta=sec^2\theta-1$$

Comment: wasn't the question $sec2\theta$ just now??? anyway it is wrong, it should be $sec^2\theta$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2 \theta \sec^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta -1$$

$$\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}= \sec^2 \theta -1$$

$$\tan^2 \theta= \sec^2 \theta -1$$

$$\tan^2 \theta  + 1= \sec^2 \theta$$

$$\sec^2 \theta= \sec^2 \theta$$

For more information, google the pythagorean identities on Khan Academy or something.

Comment: It is $sec^2 \theta,$ not $\sec 2\theta$.

Comment: Yup, I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the Pythagorean Identity $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ for $\sin^2\theta$, you obtain $\sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos^2\theta$.  Hence,

$$\sin^2\theta\sec^2\theta = (1 - \cos^2\theta)\sec^2\theta = \sec^2\theta - 1$$